# Changing parameters for a DIV auto refresh within an Ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have some content within a #DIV that is being refreshed via Jquery. I am trying to change the refresh intervals once an Ajax call has been made and then change the interval once the Ajax request has completed.

The first part works, i.e once the Ajax process starts the interval starts to refresh every 2 seconds however once Ajax has completed the #DIV is stuck refreshing every 2 secs and doesn't revert to the 60 seconds on success.

This is the code:

```
<script>
  $(function () {
   $('form').on('submit', function (e) {
        setInterval("my_function();",2000);
    $('#loadingmessage').show(); 

     e.preventDefault();
      $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'form.php',
        data: $('form').serialize(),
        success: function (data) {
            $(".content").css("visibility", "visible"); 
            $('#loadingmessage').hide();
            $('#formt').trigger("reset");   
            setInterval("my_function();",60000);
        },
  error: function(data){
    alert('error!');
   }
         });
       });
     });
  </script>
```

This sets the initial interval when the page loads:

```
<script>
 setInterval("my_function();",60000);      
    function my_function(){
    $('#div').load(location.href + ' #div');
   }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to clear first interval and then create new, see below

```
<script>
  $(function () {
   $('form').on('submit', function (e) {
        var interval = setInterval("my_function();",2000);
    $('#loadingmessage').show(); 

     e.preventDefault();
      $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'form.php',
        data: $('form').serialize(),
        success: function (data) {
            $(".content").css("visibility", "visible"); 
            $('#loadingmessage').hide();
            $('#formt').trigger("reset");   
            clearInterval(interval); // stop the interval
            setInterval("my_function();",60000);
        },
  error: function(data){
    alert('error!');
   }
         });
       });
     });
  </script>
```